# I am trying to identify a diode or modern substitute

Tags: diodes, identification

I am trying to identify a diode.  It’s from a 1970s wem echo.  The schematic shows it as a Zener diode, 18 the diode is tubular black with silver grey band at one end and writing read along it’s length and circumference which reads 1R ,1ZS ,18A.  I can’t find any information anywhere. It’s reading continuity both directions and similar resistance, any ideas on it or a modern replacement

Comment: Can you give us a link to the schematic?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in a Copicat MK4? If so I believe that it's an 18 V 1 W Zener as I see what looks like a Zener marked 18 V on the schematic.

1R is probably IR for International Rectifier, and the part number is 1ZS18A.

I found a cross reference for some 1ZSxxA diodes to 1N47xxA diodes, but only up to a 1ZS15A which crosses to 1N4744A, a 15 V Zener. All of the 1ZSxxA diodes listed have the voltage as the 'xx' part of the number. Extrapolating to an 18 V Zener that would make the 1ZS18A cross to a 1N4746A.

ECG and RCA Semiconductor Replacement Guides both show 1ZS18A cross referenced to 18 V 1 W Zeners, ECG5077A (or NTE5077A), and SK18A for the RCA. I give those numbers for completeness, or in the off case you just happen to have one already. The 1N4746A is widely available and a lot less expensive so if you have to buy one go for that.

Comment: I'll add that if this one ran hot, consider getting a higher-wattage variety if board space permits.  Or attach a heatsink to it.  Or add a small fan.  Do not extend it off of the board though, as that ironically makes it run hotter.